# Crystal Reports 2008 - Changing background color

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a subreport, and in the Group Footer, I have string, that I am trying to change the background color using the following code.

If WorkID IS equal to the Technical.workId or the Development.WorkId, then the color code works, but the other items are solid black.

[image: Example 1]

If If WorkID IS NOT equal to or null to the Technical.workId or the Development.WorkId, the my report is blank.

[image: Example 2]

```
if 
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}<>{Technical.workId}
and {Work.WorkID}<>{Development.WorkId} Then crNoColor
else if
(
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Development.WorkId} 
and {Development.PlanName}={Project.ProjectName}
and {Development.devStatus} = "R" )
then crRed
else if (
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Development.WorkId} 
and {Development.PlanName}={Project.ProjectName}
and {Development.devStatus} = "A" )
then crYellow
else if (
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Tech.workId}
and ({Resource.Team Name}like "Tech*") 
and {Technical.TechStatus} = "R" )
then crRed
else if (
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Tech.workId}
and ({Resource.Team Name}like "Tech*") 
and {Technical.TechStatus} = "A" )
then crYellow
else if (
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Tech.workId}
and ({Resource.Team Name}like "QA*") 
and {Technical.TechStatus} = "R" )
then crRed
else if (
{?Pm-DB.ID}={Work.Num} 
and {Work.WorkID}={Tech.workId}
and ({Resource.Team Name}like "QA*") 
and {Technical.TechStatus} = "A" )
then crYellow
```

Comment: My issue what I was using inner joins instead of left outer joins to the Work, Development, and Technical tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly check for null using `isnull` otherwise the formula gives up.

Comment: I did add the following code to the beginning and the subreport still does not show any results: if 
isnull({Development.WorkId})
Then crNoColor
else if 
isnull({Technology.workId})
Then crNoColor

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an else part of your statement to able to work that, if you dont want to color the blank record.. just include crNone or crWhite on your else statement

Hope this helps,

Joven